# Xcode: Unit tests compilation errors not shown

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

When running Unit tests I wrote for my iOS app, I can't see compilation errors like I do for the normal Swift code. I only get "Command SwiftCompile failed with a nonzero exit code" and need to open the Report Navigator for more details. How can I see those errors straight into the code?

I've tried to look into the build and scheme settings for something wrong or missing, but couldn't find anything.